# Record call even after my app is closed and cleared from recents

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, call-recording

I am developing an Android application, where I have asked to implement the call record ,I have gone through SO and found One Solution which is working fine when my app is opened. If I close my app or clear it from recent apps, Call record is not working. Tried searching in the Google and SO but no luck. I am posting my code here, Can some one help me in getting the solution.

CallreCorder Service class:

```
public class TService extends Service {
MediaRecorder recorder;
File audiofile;
String name, phonenumber;
String audio_format;
public String Audio_Type;
int audioSource;
Context context;
private Handler handler;
Timer timer;
Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
Toast toast;
Boolean isOffHook = false;
private boolean recordstarted = false;

private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
private CallBr br_call;




@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("service", "destroy");

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // final String terminate =(String)
    // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
    // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
    // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
    //
    // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
    // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
    // // object
    // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
    // CustomPhoneStateListener();
    // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
    // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    // context = getApplicationContext();

    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
    this.br_call = new CallBr();
    this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

    // if(terminate != null) {
    // stopSelf();
    // }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Bundle bundle;
    String state;
    String inCall, outCall;
    public boolean wasRinging = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    wasRinging = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    if (wasRinging == true) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa");
                        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                            sampleDir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        Log.d("TService", "onReceive: "+sampleDir);
                        String file_name = "Outgoing";
                        try {
                            audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".wav", sampleDir);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                      recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
//                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        recorder.start();
                        recordstarted = true;
                    }
                } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    wasRinging = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (recordstarted) {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recordstarted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
            if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa");
                if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                    sampleDir.mkdirs();
                }
                Log.d("TService", "onReceive: "+sampleDir);
                String file_name = "Record";
                try {
                    audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".wav", sampleDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                //                      recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                //                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.start();
                recordstarted = true;

            }
        }

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("callRecord"));
    }
}

}
```

Receiver class:

```
public class DeviceAdminDemo extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
};

public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
};
}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
private ComponentName mAdminName;

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE= 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkPermission()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        requestPermission();
    }

    try {
        // Initiate DevicePolicyManager.
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminDemo.class);

        if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click on Activate button to secure your application.");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            // mDPM.lockNow();
            // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            // TrackDeviceService.class);
            // startService(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("callRecord"));
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TService.class);
    startService(intent);
}


private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("callRecord")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Call record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

private boolean checkPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)){

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Allow Us pemissions. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted, ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("callRecord"));

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);

}


}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.practice.callrecorder">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver
        android:name=".DeviceAdminDemo"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".TService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

    </service>
</application>
```

my_admin.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<uses-policies>
    <force-lock />
</uses-policies>
```

any help would be grateful!!!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

use **START_STICKY** as return param of onStartCommand() so when you kill you app it will restart the service

for reference you can check android developer guide

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Will check and get back to you.